# How can I extract data from a specific column in a table, then assign it to array of variables using loop?

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to extract all the data from column B, then assign it to variables using for loop. I'm using this code, but it is looping wrong. 
Ex: 
Total row count = 10
Variable 1 to variable 10 are having the same data; then it will loop 10x. So the final values of array variables are all the same :(

```
for (int getAllAccts = 1; getAllAccts <= TotalRowCount.size(); getAllAccts++) {
try{
    String[] accName = new String[TotalRowCount.size()]
    for(int accNameCount=1; accNameCount < TotalRowCount.size(); accNameCount++){
            accName[accNameCount] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tbl-table1']/tbody/tr[" + (getAllAccts)+ "]/td[2]/a")).getText();
            log.logWarning('Customer Name' + accNameCount + ' ' + accName[accNameCount])
    }
}
catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
    String[] accName
    for(int accNameCount=1; accNameCount < TotalRowCount.size(); accNameCount++){
            accName[accNameCount] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tbl-table1']/tbody/tr[" + (getAllAccts)+ "]/td[2]/a")).getText();
            log.logWarning('Customer Name' + accNameCount + ' ' + accName[accNameCount])
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `getAllAccts` is always the same inside of the inner (nested) for loop. So all the `accName`s will have the same value.

Change

```
accName[accNameCount] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tbl-table1']/tbody/tr[" + (getAllAccts)+ "]/td[2]/a")).getText();
```

to

```
accName[accNameCount] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tbl-table1']/tbody/tr[" + (accNameCount)+ "]/td[2]/a")).getText();
```